# How to wget IMDb message board pages?

Tags: download, wget, cookies, headers

Since IMDb is planning to remove all Message Boards in 2 weeks, I'd like to fetch some pages, however `wget` fails to do so.

This is what I did:

1. Logged as user at http://www.imdb.com/boards/ page.
2. Exported cookies into `cookies.txt` file using [cookies.txt Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookiestxt/njabckikapfpffapmjgojcnbfjonfjfg).
3. Run `wget` as below (as suggested in `cookies.txt` file):

   ```
   $ wget -x --load-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies -e robots=off -A Mozilla http://www.imdb.com/boards/
   --2017-02-09 15:19:45--  http://www.imdb.com/boards/
   Resolving www.imdb.com... 54.239.23.73
   Connecting to www.imdb.com|54.239.23.73|:80... connected.
   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
   2017-02-09 15:19:46 ERROR 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable.
   ```

   This should even work without `cookies.txt`, since the page is accessible for public.

What I am missing?

Comment: I got the same error... I found a comment on another site saying "they don't like the wget useragent"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there's a few extra settings you need to add including the user agent. I added the following to my `~/.wgetrc` file and it seems to do the job. Although occasionally I'm getting a 500 or 503 error. I wonder if that might be a throttling/security mechanism.

```
header = Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
header = Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
header = Connection: keep-alive
user_agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
referer = /
robots = off
```

Got the basis for this answer from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166756/289430).

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but there is [a common initiative to backup IMDB](http://archiveteam.org/index.php?title=The_Internet_Movie_Database) by the ArchiveTeam: everyone interested can help downloading to [a common archive](http://tracker.archiveteam.org/imdb/) which eventually ends up in archive.org (see the `archiveteam` collection).

Instructions are provided. Basically, you can run a VirtualBox/VMWare appliance called *ArchiveTeam Warrior*, but I decided to go with the Linux scripts.